# Compute $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ if $a_0=3$, $a_1=5$, and $na_n=\frac23a_{n-1}-(n-1)a_{n-1}$ for every $n>1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

> Assume that $a_0=3$, $a_1=5$, and, for arbitrary  $n>1$ , $na_n=\frac{2}{3}a_{n-1}-(n-1)a_{n-1}$. Prove that, when $|x|<1$, the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ converges, and compute its sum.

I tried to let $\displaystyle a_n-a_1=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{5-6k}{3k}a_{n-1}$ , and $\displaystyle a_n=(\frac{5-3n}{3n})a_{n-1}$

$$
a_{n-1}(\frac{5-3n}{3n}-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{5-6k}{3k})=5
$$

I want to know how to continue it.

**Edit:** (after reading ideas by @JV.Stalker)

I made the following supplement

$$
S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n\\
S'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}\\
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}na_nx^n=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3}a_{n-1}x^n-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1)a_{n-1}x^n\\
[xS'(x)-5x]=\frac{2}{3}x·\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n-1}-x\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n-1}\\
x[S'(x)-5]=\frac{2}{3}x(S(x)-3)-x(xS'(x))\\
S'(x)-5=S(x)-3-xS'(x)\\
(x+1)S'(x)=\frac{2}{3}S(x)+3\\
S'(x)-\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{x+1}S(x)=\frac{3}{x+1}\\
S(x)=c(x+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}-\frac{9}{2}\\
S(0)=a_0=3\\
c=\frac{15}{2}\\
S(x)=\frac{15}{2}(x+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}-\frac{9}{2}
$$

Comment: $a_{n-1}$ twice and two conditions ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I don't know why it's written like this, but it's correct

Comment: Did you check the answer below before accepting it?

Comment: Maybe  I made a mistake as a freshman, but @JV.Stalker really helped me, also thanks very much for your remind and let me know the regulation of the community.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$na_n=\frac{5}{3}a_{n-1}-na_{n-1}$

Multiply by $x^n$ both sides and sum from $n=1$ to $\infty$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty na_n x^n=\frac{5}{3}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}x^n-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty na_{n-1}x^n$

Reindex of the RHS:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^n=\frac{5}{3}x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}x^n-x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)a_{n}x^n$

After sorting the eqution:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^n+x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty na_{n}x^n=\frac{2}{3}x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}x^n$

$(1+x)\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty na_nx^n=\frac{2}{3}x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}x^n$

Use that $nx^{n-1}=\frac{dx^n}{dx}$ and let $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$

We have the following differential eqution:

$(x+1)\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac{2}{3}f(x)$

Finally $f(x)=(x+1)^\frac{2}{3}+c$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$ is convergent.

Comment: I had two unusual things when I saw the result, the first is that I did  not use the values ${a_0}$ and ${a_1}$, the second is that the sum is convergent  for every real x.

Comment: I made the following supplement after your method, and Thanks again! @JV.Stalker

Comment: @Jack throne, It was my pleasure, if it was useful please accept my solution. Thank you.

Comment: "Finally $f(x)=(x+1)^\frac{2}{3}+c$" No, $(x+1)y'(x)=ay(x)$ is not solved by $y(x)=(x+1)^a+c$. "$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$ is convergent" ?? 1. Why? 2. For which $x$s?

Comment: Oh, and $a_1=5\ne2=\frac23a_0$ hence the expression of $f(x)$ is **wrong**. "the first is that I did not use the values a0 and a1" Indeed, this signals the solution is wrong. "the second is that the sum is convergent for every real x" It is not.

Comment: @Did Thank you for all comments, I am going to check these posts, best regards.